# jquery click() not called on document.ready

Tags: jquery

This is just a learning piece of code, this is not meant to implement a functionality.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>
        <button id="b1">I am b1 </button>
        <br/>
        <button id="b2">I am b2 </button>
    </body>

</html>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#b2").trigger('click'); // this is not hiding the b2

    $("#b2").click(); // this is not hiding the b2

    $("#b2").click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
    }); // when i click on b2 then b2 is hidden

    $("#b1").click(function () { // when i click on b1, then b2 is hidden
        $("#b2").click();
    });
});
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6k5wh9m0/

**Why is `$("#b2").click()` not called on page load?**

What I infer from this behavior is that the element `b2` might probably not available at the binding time. But is that correct? and does that also mean that we cannot call `.click()` on `document.ready()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trigger the event after registering the handler

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#b2").click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
    }); // when i click on b2 then b2 is hidden

    $("#b1").click(function () { // when i click on b1, then b2 is hidden
        $("#b2").click();
    });

    $("#b2").click(); // need to trigger the event after the handler is registered, else when the event is triggered there is nothing to do
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#b2").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
  }); // when i click on b2 then b2 is hidden

  $("#b1").click(function() { // when i click on b1, then b2 is hidden
    $("#b2").click();
  });

  $("#b2").click(); // this is not hiding the b2
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="b1">I am b1</button>
<br/>
<button id="b2">I am b2</button>
```

Comment: my bad! :) Thank you Arun P Johny. That was so quick +1. I can accept the answer only after 12 mins

Answer (score 0):

or you can:

```
$("#b2").click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
}).click();
```

or

```
$("#b2").click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
}).trigger('click');
```